# Insert a header from a HTML into VB

Tags: html, vb.net

I am currently doing a school project for an elite program that serves every user's aviation purposes, from customers to pilots. I wanted to grab a text from a website called [Fuel Planner](http://fuelplanner.com). The user will input their  departure and destination and then the website will load how much fuel is needed for that flight. However, I only need one part of that HTML which is the part where it prints the amount of fuel needed. The HTML code for that is as shown below:

```
<!-- end #menu -->
<div id="about">
<h3>Airbus A300-600-PW4158 Fuel Planner</h3>
<p>Sydney to Brisbane  YSSY-YBBN (406 NM)<br></p>
<h2>Total Fuel: 26608 POUNDS</h2>
```

The line that I need to grab is

```
<h2>Total Fuel: 26608 POUNDS</h2>
```

I want this line to be inserted into the textbox **txtFOB.Text**. 
Both are on the same form but on different tabs, so we don't have to worry about that. The web browser is called **webFuel** in the form **frmPilots**.

For this example, the departure *ORIG* is going to be

- YSSY (Sydney)

And the arrival *DEST* will be

- YBBN (Brisbane)

And the aircraft would be

- A300-600

Both can be inserted into the two text boxes on the website's home page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Comment: The site has an API that you should use.  http://fuelplanner.com/api.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element doesn't have an ID, you would need to loop thru the elements collection and look for the element you are interested in.

Try the following:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In webFuel.Document.GetElementsByTagName("H2")
    If element.InnerText Like "Total Fuel: * POUNDS" Then
        'this is the element we are looking for...
        txtFOB.Text = element.InnerText.Replace("Total Fuel:","").Replace("POUNDS","").Trim()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**NB:** You have put a lot of tags in the question which is confusing. The above code is for `VB.NET` and is not tested.

Comment: Thank you that code worked! And sorry this is my very first post in a forum :) I have one more question. Is it possible to remove the text from "Total Fuel: 26608 POUNDS" and keep the numbers only like "26608"?

Comment: You can just replace the unwanted text with empty string. I edited my answer to show how.